# How to set reference to System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit

Tags: windows-phone-7, data-visualization

I have a windows phone 7.1 project that I want to create a chart in using the silverlight 5.0 chart control. I've installed the December 2011 version of the Silverlight Toolkit.  No other versions exist on my computer.  When I try to set a reference to the the System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit.dll that is located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v5.0\Toolkit\dec11 an error message occurs. The message says "A higher reference version or incompatable assembly cannot be added to the project."  I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and the Target Windows Phone OS version is set to Windows Phone OS 7.1 which is the usual reason I've seen for this error message.  Does anybody know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the right toolkit.
[WP7 Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/75888#DownloadId=304100)

You **Cannot** use the Silverlight 5 Toolkit in a WP7 application

After that its pretty simple:

1. Add the dll to the project as a reference.
2. In any XAML you want to use the items place a declaration (Just to name a few)

   ```
   xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit"
   xmlns:customControl="clr-namespace:TriviaGame.CustomControls;assembly=TriviaGame.CustomControls"
   xmlns:visualizationToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit" 
   xmlns:charting="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
   ```

Comment: I downloaded the Silverlight for Windows Phone toolkit and installed it (after removing another it apparently detected). Now I'm trying to find a reference to System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting which doesn't show up when I try to add a reference on the .Net Tab of the add reference form nor can I find a a path that will lead me to this dll when I use the Browse tab of the add reference form.

Comment: Add the reference to the project. Rebuild it (make sure it compiles) Open the designer. Add this to the top. xmlns:charting="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"

Comment: The path wont be in the .Net tab. You have to Browse to it: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v5.0\Toolkit\dec11\Bin

Comment: What is the path where it is stored -- I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: Thanks for the path -- didn't see it just then.

Comment: Use C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v5.0\Toolkit\dec11\Bin for x64 bit machines

Comment: Can you mark this as an answer and upvote if you can...thanks

Comment: I did look on the path c:\Program Files(x86) but when I browsed the entire path you mentioned there were no executable files? Any suggestions?

Comment: No why would there be. References are libraries which are dll's. Add the dll's you want to the project as a reference

Comment: Executables is just what the file type says when I use the Browse feature when setting the reference. I didn't see any dll files when I used the windows explorer either. The only file types in the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v5.0\Toolkit\dec11\Bin were Program Debug Database and xml document types.

Comment: Ugh you need more help that this. Take a programming class

Comment: That's pretty lame - you tell me to look for a dll file and when I tell you it's not there you decide I need help.  If one of the files that was there was of the type that could be used for a reference don't you think it should have appeared on the list of files that could be added as a reference when I browsed to the folder with the add reference form in visual studio?  I think you've just run out of patience which is fair but let's be honest about it.

Comment: Well I want to chat with you but you dont have enough reps. A reference is a dll. If you dont have the dll's in that bin folder then its not installed. You just dont understand the basics. You should already know what a reference is and how to add one. And you should definitely know they are dll's. I answered the question already...if you have more start a new thread